# Restful Rails Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have 2 models.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts, :class_name => "CompanyAccount"
end

class CompanyAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
  resources :accounts
end
```

I have companies_controller.rb and accounts_controller.rb.

The following line doesn't work because @account's class is not Account but CompanyAccount.

```
= form_for [@company, @account] do
```

What's the best way to resolve this name mismatch?

Thanks.

Comment: What happends when you use resources :company_accounts in your routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your routes.rb file,

The code should still be

```
resources :companies do |c|
  c.resources :company_accounts
end
```

It does not matter what you name in your association has_many <association_name>, the resource name should always reflect the name of your actual model and not the ActiveRecord association. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
= form_for @account, :as => :company_account, :url => company_account_path(@company, @account)
```